# Convert gmtime() to 4 byte hex

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, hex

I have the time in this format:

```
Fri, 19 Dec 2014 03:55:24
```

and I want to convert it to a 4 byte hexadecimal value. My question is similar to this one: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867877/getting-a-datetime-in-this-format-and-converting-to-4-byte-hex), but the difference is that I have a different format, and I use the `gmtime()` function because I want the date since the Epoch. This is what I tried so far (by trying to break the code from the answer of the similar question into smaller parts):

```
ut = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S ", time.gmtime())
time.strptime(ut, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: uncoverted data remains:
```

Could you please help me?
I know that it is a simple question, but I cannot see what is the problem.

Comment: `gmtime()` returns UTC time. Given UTC time, you can get "seconds since Epoch" number but they are **different** things. Are you sure that the input time string (e.g., "Fri, 19 Dec 2014 03:55:24") is in UTC (and not in you local timezone)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing space in the format string used in

```
ut = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S ", time.gmtime())
```

The line should read:

```
ut = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
```

Without the space after %S, it runs on my side!

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps:

1. [Parse rfc 5322 time string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279) into an object that represent the broken-down time

   ```
   import email.utils
   time_tuple = email.utils.parsedate("Fri, 19 Dec 2014 03:55:24")
   ```
2. Convert the broken-down time into "seconds since Epoch" number

   ```
   import calendar
   timestamp = calendar.timegm(time_tuple) # assume input time is in UTC
   ```
3. Print the number in hex format

   ```
   print('%08X' % timestamp)
   # -> 5493A1AC
   ```